# How can I generate test files with specific extensions and sizes for my application's upload feature?

Tags: file, testing, upload, generator, dummy-data

I need to generate files with different extensions like .jpg, .png, .pdf, .csv, .docx, .xslx etc. so I can test uploading files in my application. I need a quick solution here.

I tried to create files by terminal but these files contain null bytes. I also scrolled the internet to find some online generators and the only solution so far was to run node.js script but it's a bit tricky as it requires a lot of struggle and attempts to make the files the exact size (especially that I am not a programmer, it was my first time with node.js at all).
Can anyone help me?